# How to make div's go to display:none when part of the div is touching the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive web design and I'm familiar with media queries. What I want to accomplish is a menu bar which comprises of floated divs each representing a button and when the browser window is shrunk, the div furthest to the right of the screen disappears as the viewport is shrunk and starts to touch it. And as the viewport keeps shrinking, the next div disappears as it's touched and so on.

What I do not want is half a div visible as the browser window shrinks.

I could accomplish this using media queries if the menu bar was a fixed with, however the number of elements in the menu bar is variable and the elements inside the menu bar are variable width too, depending on what the user has chosen to appear in their menu bar.

Any suggestions please

Comment: Sounds like you'll need Javascript for that, CSS certainly can't.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added a Javascript tag to the question as I would be interested in Javascript solutions as well.

Comment: It's expected on SO that you research this for yourself first. If you can't get **your** code to work *then* we can step in.

Comment: And why are you assuming I haven't tried to research it myself first?

Comment: `onResize` and `if object.left + object.width > document.width -> add css` something like that in JavaScript.

Comment: @Hardworker I assume that because I have no evidence to the contrary. If you had JS you should have provided it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Got it. You made a false assumption based on nothing. I suggest you give people the benefit of the doubt and go easy on the patronising. See Rics's answer for a good example of how people should behave on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given HTML like this:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div>abcdef</div><div>ghi</div><div>jklmno</div><div>pqr</div><div>stuvwx</div><div>yz</div>
</div>
```

… and CSS like this:

```
.menu {white-space: nowrap;}
.menu > div {display: inline-block;}
```

First, set all children to display.
Then, while the menu's scroll width is greater than its offset width, hide the last visible child.

**JavaScript**

```
function updateMenu() {
  var menu= document.querySelector('.menu'),
      d= menu.querySelectorAll('div');

  for(var i = 0 ; i < d.length ; i++) {
    d[i].style.display= '';
  }

  for(var i = d.length - 1 ; menu.scrollWidth > menu.offsetWidth ; i--) {
    d[i].style.display= 'none';
  }
}
```

You can add that to a window.resize event:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', updateMenu);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3yy1m4s/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you'll have to use javascript. You can get the viewport height/width [pretty easily](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/) and write a quick loop checking if the bar is wider than the current viewport width, and if so, removing the last div. Then assign the function to a resize handler, like so: (pseudo code)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    get child divs of menu;
    while(menuWidth > viewport) {
        lastChildDiv.css("display","hidden");
    }
});
```

Normally one would use columns that switch to being stacked, use variable-size divs (vh/vw dimensions), or switch to a different menu (often a popup type) when the viewport is too small.